# nth derivative of a troublesome function

Tags: functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I don't know where to start on this problem.

I'm trying to get the 2015th derivative(at x = 0) of f(x) = x^2 * arctan(x).

Doing the derivatives one by one seems a little troublesome... What do you suggest I do first?

Answer (score 1):

Use the taylor series of $\arctan x$

$$\arctan x = x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \dots $$

This you can prove by integrating the infinite series for $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \dots$